# clearing the contents of an input textbox using onblur event handler

Tags: javascript

i have an input box whose value i want to clear if the user's input is wrong. i want to accomplish this using the onblur event and a javascript function.

this is the textfield i want to apply the onblur function to:

```
<tr>
     <td><input id="TryMe" type="text" onblur="checkMe('TryMe')"/></td>
</tr>
```

the function that does that is this:

```
<script>

function checkMe(elemID){

    elem = document.getElementById(elemID);

    if (elemID.value == "CORRECT"){
        alert ("you are correct!");
    }

    else{

          document.getElementById(numericElemID).value="";
          document.getElementById(numericElemID).focus();
          return false;

    }

}
```

and it works as i intend it to. however, why is it that when i remove the "return false;" part, it does not work anymore:

```
        else {
        document.getElementById(numericElemID).value="";
        document.getElementById(numericElemID).focus();
    }
```

EDIT: including the javascript and the text input

Comment: Can we see all the JavaScript?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: by does not work i mean that the contents of the input box are not erased

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function checkMe(elemID) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(elemID);

    if (elem.value == "CORRECT") {
        alert("you are correct!");
    } else elem.value = "";
}
document.getElementById('TryMe').onblur = function () { checkMe('TryMe') }
```